# Log4j - trim field value in log

Tags: java, logging, log4j

In my entity I have a specific field containing many characters, and I need to log only the first 200 of them. How can this be achieved with log4j?

### EDIT

From my knowledge below patterns can be used when formatting whole output - but I need to format just one certain field from my response model. Maybe there is some annotation indicating "hey, just grab first 200 characters from this value and put that in log"?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [PatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) and trim the field with:

```
%.200
```

for example:

```
%-6r [%15.15t] %-5p %30.30 c %x - %m%n
```

For further information read up here:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html